# lighttpd PHP Error: 403 - Forbidden

Tags: php, lighttpd, http-status-code-403

I have been trying to configure a web server using lighttpd on Windows. After installing PHP, everytime I try to access a PHP file from the directory 'htdocs,' I get the error: '403 - Forbidden.' I have followed this tutorial to setup lighttpd: http://joshdick.net/writing/lighttpd. I have searched Google, but haven't found any good documentation on this problem. FYI: I'm pretty new to this. I have the content of my 'lighttpd-inc.conf' file [here](http://trykinchat.com/temporary/lighttpd-inc.conf).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things this could be.  For instance, if you are using FastCGI on Windows there may be an issue (they don't play nice).  It could be as simple as your folder permissions (in Windows) don't allow access to this folder.  However, after trying to look over your .conf file (the lack of line breaks makes it a bear to read), I have a place you could start looking.

It looks like you are referring to the path to htdocs improperly.  For example, this line here:

```
server.document-root = "HTDOCS/"
```

I don't think that path will work properly.  Usually you have to have a "/HTDOCS/" style path.  There are a number of lines like this throughout your file.  Here is a link to some documentation on this:

http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/server.document-rootdetails

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried that, although I don't think that is the issue as when I try to access localhost or 127.0.0.1, I still get the default lighttpd index.html. Viewing the source of my .conf file makes it much easier to read. Thanks again!

Comment: @Kincaid - if you put localhost or the IP address, that is a full path.  When you put a folder name, you have to have a leading backslash to denote a directory below the main.  Good tip on the view source.  It worked like a charm.  I forgot about trying that.

Answer (score 0):

Your cgi/fcgi to your php is not configured correctly. CGI or FCGI is the glue that binds PHP and lighttpd together.
check your lighttpd error.log
it will state something like:

```
(mod_fastcgi.c.1397) [ERROR]: spawning fcgi failed.
```

i use:

```
fastcgi.server = ( ".php" => ((                                      
                     "bin-path" => "/bin/php-cgi",             
                     "socket" => "/tmp/php.socket",              
                     "max-procs" => 1,                                     
                     "bin-environment" => (                         
                       "PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" => "16",                    
                       "PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" => "10000"           
                     ),         
                     "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"
                 )))
```

make sure that fastcgi is enabled in modules.conf

```
server.modules = (
  "mod_access",
  "mod_fastcgi",
#  "mod_alias",
#  "mod_auth",
#  "mod_evasive",
#  "mod_redirect",
#  "mod_rewrite",
#  "mod_setenv",
#  "mod_usertrack",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to enable the fastcgi module and the php configuration. To perform that run the following commands:

```
sudo lighty-enable-mod fastcgi
sudo lighty-enable-mod fastcgi-php
sudo systemctl restart lighttpd.service
```