# 403 error on Localhost php file

Tags: php, wamp, http-status-code-403

I am trying to access my php file(I am using codegniter) but getting 403 error acces denied, Even I was working on it yesterday It was fine. Still I am able to access the rest of the pages. How can i solve this?

```
You don't have permission to access /project/newsletter/ on this server.
```

Comment: Perhaps this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246584/lighttpd-php-error-403-forbidden?rq=1

Comment: I am using wamp not xamp, this link is about xamp

Comment: The 'x'/'w' shouldn't make a difference. The permissions will be set by the 'a' - apache. Are you trying to access the root of the /project/newsletter folder? You might get an error like this back if you try to access a folder that does not contain an index file and directory listing is disallowed.

Comment: It looks like you are ( or should be ) using a Virtual Host. Add you Vhost definition to the question. That is probably where your issue is.